# Как удобнее проинициализировать объект

Tags: c#, ооп, grpc

Создаю сервис, в нем есть объекты типа - пользователи, монеты.

У пользователя есть монеты, монеты хранят в себе ид и историю.

Я хочу создать 105 монет, надо как-то проинициализировать поля(ид и историю).

Я решил проблему таким способом - создал массив, жестко захардкодив размерность, а в конструкторе прошелся по всем элементам и назначил Id.

Выглядит это примерно вот так

```
            int id = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayCoins.Length; i++)
            {
                arrayCoins[i] = new Coin { Id = id++, History = "История" };
            }
```

Выглядит это нелепо, но других методов не пришло в голову. Может быть Вы поделитесь?)

Comment: `создал массив, жестко захардкодив размерность` - и в чем проблема если надо создать именно 105 монет? ну и да, переменная `id` не нужна (если дальше её не использовать), потому что можно сделать так `new Coin { Id = ++i, History = "История" };`

Comment: @Pekor дело в том, что необязательно создавать именно 105 монет. может быть разное количество. а на счет id спасибо, поправлю

Comment: А зачем монете `id`? Вы её в базу будете записывать или куда `id` этот нужен?

Comment: @CrazyElf ид нужен по условию. базу не обязательно использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Красиво можно сделать через `Linq`:

```cs
var n = 105;
var coins = Enumerable.Range(1, n)
                      .Select(x => new Coin { Id = x, History = "История" })
                      .ToArray();
```

Comment: спасибо! не могу ответ лайкнуть, репутации не хватает.